# Inconsistent results of wave objects in R

Tags: r, audio

I'm trying to test out how well R can handle audio analyses using `tuneR`, but I've been having some trouble. 
When I try to get R to play back an mp3 I've stored on my computer using this code

```
holiday=readMP3("C:\\Users\\User1\\Downloads\\holiday_music.mp3")
play(holiday)
```

I received 3 different results depending on the mp3 I used. 

1. R starts playing this cacaphonous sound that I can't decipher that cannot be stopped 
2. R returns this error message 
"Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or a required codec might not be installed on your computer."

 3. R actually plays the mp3

 Any ideas for this discrepancy in playback between different mp3s?

Comment: You'll need to post a reproducible example to get help for a question like this.  Find (or put) some mp3 files online that illustrate the bad behaviour, and include links to them in your question.

Comment: It's somewhat hard because these mp3's are songs that are copyrighted. I'll have to look for free-to-use music, reporduce the error and update this at a later time